# show that $\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_n) = \gcd(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2},\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a_{i_0} \neq 0$ for some $i_0 \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. How to show that $\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_n) = \gcd(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2},\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n))$. (Hint: show that the sets of the common factors of the left and right side are the same).

Question is Exercise 1.9 on pp252 in Elementary Number Theory by Gareth Jones.

Comment: This is extremely straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: I have got following. gcd($a_1, \dots, a_n$) = gcd($a_1, \dots, a_{n-2}$,gcd($a_{n-1},a_n$)) <=> $x_1a_1+ \dots + x_na_n = x_1a_1 + \dots + x_{n-2} a_{n-2} + x_{n-1}(x_{n-1}a_{n-1}+x_na_n)$ <=> ?

Comment: What do you think about the hint?

Comment: I don't know how to show that they have same sets.

Comment: I’d say that you’re on the wrong track altogether and need to start over. You need to show that every common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2},\operatorname{gcd}(a_{n-1},a_n)$ and vice versa. Start with some $d$ that divides each of $a_1$ through $a_n$ and show that it divides each number in the second list; then start with some $d$ that divides every number in the second list and show that it divides each of the $a_i$.

Comment: A clue, fundamental theorem of arithmetic would make the proof inmediate.

Comment: I have got this far: gcd($a_1, \dots, a_n$) thus d|$a_i$, $i=1, \dots n$ and gcd($a_1, \dots, a_{n-2},gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n))$ thus d|$a_j$, $j=1, \dots, n-2$. How would you continue from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t want to be rude or overly discouraging, but I’m not sure that you’re ready for this material: what you wrote in that last comment doesn’t make a whole lot of sense. Let’s try this: I’ll take you through half of the argument in detail and give you a chance to use that as a model for the second half.

You want to show that $\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) = \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_{n-2},\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n))$; one way to do this is to show that every common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$. In other words, you want to show that the set of common divisors of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$ is equal to the set of common divisors of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$. One very common way to show that two sets are equal is to show that every member of the first set is a member of the second, and *vice versa*. I’ll show that every common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$ and leave you to show that every common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$.

Suppose that $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$. This means that $d \mid a_1,d \mid a_2,\dots,$ $d\mid a_{n-1}$, and $d\mid a_n$. To show that $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$, we must show that $d\mid a_1,d\mid a_2,\dots,d\mid a_{n-2}$, and $d\mid \gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$. By hypothesis $d \mid a_1,d \mid a_2,\dots,$ $d\mid a_{n-2}$, so we really only have to show that $d\mid\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$.

For brevity let $\delta = \gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$; then $\delta\mid a_{n-1}$ and $\delta\mid a_n$. But that’s true of *any* common divisor of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$, and $\delta$ isn’t just any old common divisor of these two numbers: it’s the *greatest* common divisor. This implies that *every* common divisor of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ is a divisor of $\delta$: this is an important property of the greatest common divisor that gets used over and over. In particular, $d\mid\delta$, since $d$ is a common divisor of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$. And that’s exactly what we needed: we’ve now shown that if $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$, then it’s also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$.

Now see if you can manage the opposite direction: if $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$, then $d$ is also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$. If anything, it’s a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \  d\ |\ a,b,c,c'\! \iff d\ |\ a,b,\ \color{#c00}{\color{#c00}d\ |\ c,c'}\! \iff\! d\ |\ a,b,\color{#c00}{(c,c')}.\, $ Keep repeating that.

It boils down to associativity of $\wedge\:$ ("logical and"), where $\rm\ d\ |\ a,b,c\ :=\ d\:|\:a \wedge (d\:|\:b \wedge d\:|\:c)$ combined with the [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356075/242) $\rm\, \color{#c00}{d\mid x,y\iff d\mid (x,y)}$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) for more on associativity of gcd.

Answer (score 0):

Origin - Elementary Number Theory, Jones,
p9, Exercises 1.8 and 1.9

I refashion Brian M. Scott's answer in Jones's way.

> Exercise 1.8 - c|a and c|b $\iff c|\gcd(a,b)$
>
> Exercise 1.9 - Your claim.

**Proof of Forward Direction -**
Postulate that $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$. This means that $d \mid a_1,d \mid a_2,\dots,$ $\color{brown}{d\mid a_{n-1}, and \; d\mid a_n}$. To show that $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$, we must show that $d\mid a_1,d\mid a_2,\dots,d\mid a_{n-2}$, and $d\mid \gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$. By hypothesis $d \mid a_1,d \mid a_2,\dots,$ $d\mid a_{n-2}$, so we really only have to show that $d\mid\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$.

But by cause of the forward direction of Exercise 1.8, $\color{brown}{d\mid a_{n-1}, and \; d\mid a_n} \implies d|\gcd(a_{n - 1}, a_n)$.

**Proof of Backward Direction -**  Postulate that $d$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-2}$ and $\color{seagreen}{\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)}$. I want to prove $d$ is also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$. The only difference is to prove
$\color{brown}{d\mid a_{n-1}, and \; d\mid a_n}$.

By cause of the backward direction of Exercise 1.8, $ d|\color{seagreen}{\gcd(a_{n - 1}, a_n)} \implies \color{brown}{d\mid a_{n-1}, and \; d\mid a_n}$. Then $d$ is also a common divisor of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$, and $a_n$.