# How is following possible: $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Following is [extract from the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62496/show-that-gcda-1-dots-a-n-gcda-1-dots-a-n-2-gcda-n-1-a-n/62517#62517) that proves following: Let $a_1,\dots, a_n$, such that $a_{i_0} \neq 0$. Show that $\gcd(a_1,\dots, a_n)=\gcd(a_1,\dots, a_{n-2},\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n))$(hint! Show that left side and right side sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ of common factors are the same. So basically $A_1 \subset A_2$ and $A_2 \subset A_1$.

> If $k \in A_2$, then $k \mid a_i$ $\forall i=1, \dots, n-2$ and $k \mid \gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n)$. Secondly $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_n$ so by transitivity $k\mid a_{n-1}$ and $k \mid a_n$. Therefore $k \in A_1$ in other words $A_2 \subset A_1$?
>   How is following possible: $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_{n-1}$ and $\gcd(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_n$? Would someone unravel the reasons that one can claim following to be true?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_n)$ is the greatest common divisor, so of course it divides $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$.  That's the definition of divisor.

Comment: In general, $gcd(a,b)\mid a$ and $gcd(a,b)\mid b$.  That's because $gcd(a,b)$ is a *common* divisor of $a$ and $b$.  This proof is just using $a=a_{n-1}$ and $b=a_n$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget about the entire rest of the problem; given any two integers $x$ and $y$, 
$$\gcd(x,y)\mid x\quad\text{ and }\quad \gcd(x,y)\mid y.$$
The **definition** of $\gcd(x,y)$ is that it is the greatest integer having this property (hence the name, **greatest common divisor**).

Then, let $x=a_{n-1}$ and $y=a_n$.