# Reckoning or anthyphairesis: process and intuition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I encountered the process called "Anthyphairesis" which apparently was the basis of the Euclidean algorithm and was also described in Chinese writings under the name "reckoning".

A description of the "reckoning" algorithm:

> The method for simplifying parts: Take the numerator from
> thedenominator; in turn take the denominator from the numerator. When
> thenumbers [on the sides of] the numerator and denominator are equal
> to oneanother, then you can go on to simplify.

I am trying to understand the idea behind it by using an analogy of movements along the number line.
E.g. if we want to apply the process for $8$ and $3$ then it could be something like:

[image]

But I am confused on the process itself. I think the idea is that we move around in steps of the two numbers we are working on until we reach some limit, but I am not clear on how the process would work.

Could someone help on this?

Comment: I think it must be describing the original Euclidean algorithm: repeatedly subtract the larger number from the smaller until the two numbers are equal.  This is the gcd.  The algorithm described, if taken literally, wouldn't converge, would it?

Comment: @saulspatz: I was under the impression that by these subtractions/movements we would end up shifting along the number line till we either end in $1$ or $0$ and then it stops. E.g. if we end up in $1$ then $1 + 8 = 9 - 3 - 3 - 3 = 0$ but I am not clear on how to do this in the general way or if I am totally confused

Comment: I see that I said "subtract the larger from the smaller" where I meant, of course, "subtract the smaller from the larger".  I don't see how the literal algorithm works.  Say we have $(5,15)$. The algorithm seems to give $$(5,15)\to(5,10)\to(-5,10)\to(-5,15)\to(-20,15)\to\cdots$$  Perhaps one is supposed to take absolute values.  Then it's Euclid's algorithm again.

Comment: @saulspatz: the quote I mentioned is from the TheSuàn shù shū Writings on reckoning commentary of Christopher Cullen p41

Comment: In modern language it boils down to the *subtractive* (vs. mod / remainder) form of the Euclidean algorithm (and its manifestation in closely related objects, e.g. [continued fractions, mediants, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242). But historical use an meaning is more complicated, e.g. David Fowler has written much on it, e.g. see [Ratio in early greek mathematics](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183544897) or his book [The mathematics of Plato's acacdemy: a new reconstruction](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183544897)).

Comment: The 2nd book link above should be to [this review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-mathematics-of-platos-academy-a-new-reconstruction)

Comment: @BillDubuque: The subtractive is using e.g. $133 = 1(85) + 48$?

Comment: The subtractive form repeatedly subtracts the smaller from the larger until they are equal (for positive integers), e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624165/242).

Answer (score 1):

A number line may not offer a useful context for understanding anthyphairesis because it works with a single unit corresponding to the interval between 0 and 1.  anthyphairesis and the Euclidean algorithm entail relations between multiple units: first a dividend unit and a divisor unit and also remainder unit(s) if the dividend is not a multiple of the divisor.   So parallel line segments are better resources.  But the units need to be explicitly labeled.

Let's imagine that line segments (or fraction bars) A and B are in the ratio of 10:7, but a student has not been told this.
The student measures A with B, finding it fits once, leaving a first remainder,R1.  She then measures B with R1, obtaining a quotient of 2 and leaving a remainder, R2.  Finally, she finds that R1 measures exactly 3 R2's.

If we assign the value of 1 to R2, we can infer that A = 10 and B=7.

Note also that the quotients obtained were (1;2,3).  These also allow us to represent A/B as a simple continued fraction:
A=1+ (1/(2+1/3)).  It is useful to actually diagram these ideas to better understand how the quantities are interrelated.